# Failed to establish TLS connection when downloading vscode-server with VSCode remote container

Tags: node.js, ssl, visual-studio-code, tls1.2, vscode-remote

I tried to attach to a container from Mac OS X.
I got messages below.

```
[0 ms] Start: Resolving remote
[1 ms] Setting up container rails_web_1

[43 ms] Start: Check Docker is running
[70 ms] Start: Inspecting container
[123 ms] Start: Run in container: uname -m
[361 ms] x86_64
[361 ms] 
[361 ms] Start: Run in container: (cat /etc/os-release || cat /usr/lib/os-release) 2>/dev/null
[373 ms] PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch)"
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="9"
VERSION="9 (stretch)"
ID=debian
HOME_URL="https://www.debian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://www.debian.org/support"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.debian.org/"
[373 ms] 
[374 ms] Start: Run in container: cat /etc/passwd
[377 ms] Start: Run in container: test -d /root/.vscode-server
[380 ms] 
[380 ms] 
[380 ms] Start: Run in container: set -o noclobber ; mkdir -p '/root/.vscode-server/data/Machine' && { > '/root/.vscode-server/data/Machine/.writeMachineSettingsMarker' ; } 2> /dev/null
[386 ms] 
[386 ms] 
[386 ms] Exit code 2
[388 ms] Start: Run in container: # Copy .gitconfig
[391 ms] .gitconfig exists
[391 ms] 
[391 ms] Start: Run in container: test -d /root/.vscode-server/bin/26076a4de974ead31f97692a0d32f90d735645c0
[393 ms] 
[393 ms] 
[393 ms] Exit code 1
[393 ms] Installing VS Code Server for commit 26076a4de974ead31f97692a0d32f90d735645c0
[393 ms] Start: Run in container: mkdir -p /root/.vscode-server/bin/26076a4de974ead31f97692a0d32f90d735645c0_1580278754058
[398 ms] 
[398 ms] 
[398 ms] Start: Downloading VS Code Server
[531 ms] Error: Client network socket disconnected before secure TLS connection was established
        at connResetException (internal/errors.js:559:14)
        at TLSSocket.onConnectEnd (_tls_wrap.js:1355:19)
        at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:288:20)
        at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:205:15)
        at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1154:12)
        at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:9)
```

It seems to failed establishing TLS connection.
I checked the version of related tools on the container. But I think it is not too old.

```
# openssl version
OpenSSL 1.1.0l  10 Sep 2019
# node --version
v10.18.1
```

What should I do in the next?

Answer (score 0):

This was an issue caused by my firewall setting.
This was solved when I disabled firewall.